# Why do deactivated layers still appear in the Processing Modeler's wizard in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm quite new to the graphical modeler of QGIS (version 3.10.1). It's a great tool, still, something has been bugging me for a while. I've created a fairly long model, saving the outputs of some tools as shapefiles as I need them for further analysis.

I use these newly generated shapefiles later in the model (inputed as vector layers), but have deactivated them when running the first block of my model where they are not needed (I don't launch everything at the same time as I have very big datasets and crashes often occur).

Still, in the computing wizard, it is still required to select these newly generated shapefiles, or shapefiles which will be generated further down in the model. I can't launch the model without them. What's the point of deactivating a layer and still needing to compute it in the drop down banners in the wizard? I've looked around for a related question, couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I think it would really help understand the problem if we had a screenshot of the model.

Comment: Please share some screenshots, I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you save the outputs for every tool to disk or maybe you simply assign them an output name but keep them in memory. You could simply forego generating an output layer. You can still use the product of the tool in subsequent steps without having to choose any indermediate layer.

For example, in the following screenshot, almost all processing tools could output a layer, but I simply skipped saving them. The tool's output is used in the next tool, but when the entire model finishes running, only the last layer is saved and, when you run the model, is the only one that needs to be specified a path (or not if you want to keep it as a virtual layer).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To start with, there is no such thing as stupid questions. 
If you feel that there must be an option not to have those layers appear in the list, you can make a feature request [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Feature%20Request&template=feature_request.md&title=). The developers might agree and add that in their pipeline.